# Create dashed line with standard length and standard interval

Tags: qgis, line, splitting, dash

For a project, I need to create a **dashed line** (from scratch, or possibly also out of a solid line).
The dashes need to have a standard length of 1 meter, but (and here's the difficulty) the intervals between the dashes always need to be 1,5 meter standard. So I can't use the vector split method (and delete the interval-parts), because the length of the dashes and intervals is not the same.

Does anyone have a fix/plugin/tip for this one?
Is splitting by attribute an option?

Workcase: drawing/digitalizing white street lines

Comment: Please include the software you're using in your question. It is also unclear, whether this is a symbolgy or a geometry issue. If the latter, why?

Comment: I'm working with QGIS. It's a geometry issue. How do I create those kind of lines automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the dash geometry based on your line layer by:

1. Create points along geometries with a distance of 2.5 m
2. Buffer them by 0.75 m
3. Difference with your lines as input and buffers as overlay:

[image]